# laravel echo does not send the message

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, websocket, pusher

I created a real-time chat using pusher and laravel-echo, but in production on the heroku app, the pusher doesn't give any errors, it doesn't give any errors in the console, however, the messages are not sent. Locally it works normally, except if you add hsHost to the Echo wsHost object:

`import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST.`

Bootstrap.js:

```
 window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'pusher',
   key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
   cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'sa1',    
   wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
   wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
   forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
   enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],

 });
```

broadicating.php

```
 'pusher' => [
      'driver' => 'pusher',
      'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
      'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
      'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
      'options' => [
           'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),     
           'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
           'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
           'encrypted' => true,
           'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
       ],
       'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
       ],
   ],
```

Events broadcast:

```
class SendPrivate implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    
     private $mensagem;
    private $user;
    public function __construct($mensagem , User $user)
    {
        $this->mensagem = $mensagem;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
           new PrivateChannel('User.'. $this->user->id)
        ];
    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
       return  [
            'mensagem' => $this->mensagem,
       ];
    }
}
```

Vue:

```
Echo.private('User.' + idLogado.value).listen('SendPrivate', (e) => {  
 
   messages.value.push(e.mensagem);
   scrollBottom();
});
```

Heroku reveal variables

```
VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY= ********  
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER = mt1  
VITE_PUSHER_HOST = ws-mt1.pusher.com  
VITE_PUSHER_PORT = 443  
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME = https
```

Pusher credentials env

```
PUSHER_APP_KEY= ******** 
PUSHER_APP_SECRET= ********  
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER = mt1  
PUSHER_HOST = ws-mt1.pusher.com  
PUSHER_PORT = 443  
PUSHER_SCHEME = https
```

Some solutions I saw say the problem was with the cluster, but I changed the cluster and it didn't work, I also added and removed the host from window.echo and it didn't solve it in both cases. Locally it only works if I implement a queue. I run this command in the terminal:

`php artisan queue:work database --daemon --tries=5`

So I implemented a queue in Heroku, but it didn't work either.

`worker php artisan queue:listen`

No errors appear in the console.

Comment: What does the heroku logs say? `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: Kind off difficult to help without logs or try and error. I've a live chat app running, I can show you how I did it, I had the same problem. In local everything was working fine, on deployment it didn't work. When you send a message, the message appears on the other client when you reload the page?

Comment: Hello, Adi, the heroku logs show that: 2023-11-09T10:49:49.814660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/message/store" host=alueasy-a02cceb20bff.herokuapp.com request_id=440bc997-5827-4171-904f-5987417134af fwd="45.168.147.203" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=44ms status=200 bytes=1260 protocol=https

Comment: 2023-11-09T10:49:49.814298+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.47.243 - - [09/Nov/2023:10:49:49 +0000] "POST /api/message/store HTTP/1.1" 200 - "https://alueasy-a02cceb20bff.herokuapp.com/chat" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36   
2023-11-09T10:49:50.287573+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2023-11-09 10:49:50 App\Events\SendPrivate ......................... RUNNING
2023-11-09T10:49:50.305718+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2023-11-09 10:49:50 App\Events\SendPrivate .................... 18.25ms DONE

Comment: the message appears on the other client when you reload the page? R: Yes. 

I've a live chat app running, I can show you how I did it, I had the same problem - R: I would be flattered, thank you very much. It will help me a lot

Comment: Sorry my English, not my native language

Comment: @Adi, forgot target you, sorry

Comment: @ZeNix forgot target you, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem a time ago, I fixed it editing the `broadcasting.php` file inside `config` folder:

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => true,
            'useTLS' => true,
            'encryption_master_key_base64' => env('PUSHER_MASTER_KEY')
        ],
    ],
```

For the `encryption_master_key` you can generate one using `openssl rand -base64 32` in a terminal, you'll need **[openssl](https://www.openssl.org/source/)**, set the key in your `.env` file and should be good to go.

In the JS part, this is how I've did it:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/with-encryption';

window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: false,
    encrypted: true,
});
```

In your `.env` file, set the `APP_URL` to the complete url to your app, set the `PUSHER_HOST` to the Heroku host url. So, don't forget to add all those environment variables to Heroku. You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to forward your local project in order to test prior to deploy in Heroku.

Comment: Although this was my way to go, it probably doesn't exactly work for your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I created PUSHER_MASTER_KEY and added OpenSSL key, added heroku app url in app_url. But it hasn't worked yet. Would the pusher host be the entire url of the PUSHER_SOCKET_URL?
Would it be the PUSHER_URL url?
Would it just be ws-cluster-pusher.com?
Or would it be api-cluster.pusher.com?
The location is in Virginia USA

Comment: Another thing, is it not necessary to put these variables in Heroku variables?
vite_pusher_app_cluster
vite_pusher_host
vite_pusher_app_key

Apart from the others that don't have to do with the pusher

Comment: my routes are within api.php, the route for sending messages does not have middleware, but the route for get messages between users has sactum middleware. Could this cause any problems? Although there are no errors in the console, I fixed the errors that I had related to this.

Comment: Those variables are data you're importing from `.env`, so yes, you must have them in the heroku environment variables. Pusher host will be your app hostname, it's the URL `stackoverflow.com` for example, without URL elements, it's the same as your `APP_URL` but without `http://` or the rest of the elements

Comment: Why you have your routes to send the messages in the api.php?

Comment: Thank you, so much!!! I  managed to solve the problem